# Devise/OmniAuth not signing in some users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, twitter, omniauth, twitter-oauth

Our product is a Rails application; authentication is handled with Devise and OmniAuth. ~2000 users total. We've recently had reports of some users not being able to sign in, but we can't figure out why. Not getting any server errors or anything in our production logs to suggest anything is awry.

Let's look at some code…

```
class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

  ...

  def twitter
    oauthorize "twitter"
  end

  private

  def oauthorize(provider)
    if env['omniauth.auth']
      @identity = Identity.from_omniauth(env['omniauth.auth'])
      @person = @identity.person
      # 1. failing here? Maybe?
      if @person
        PersonMeta.create_for_person(@person, session[:referrer], session[:landing_page]) if @person.first_visit?
        # 2. PersonMetas *aren't* being created.
        flash[:notice] = I18n.t("devise.omniauth_callbacks.success", kind: provider)
        sign_in_and_redirect(@person, :event => :authentication)
        # 3. Definitely failing by here…
      else
        redirect_to root_url
      end
    else
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end
end

class Identity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person, counter_cache: true, touch: true
  after_create :check_person

  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(auth.slice("provider", "uid")).first_or_initialize.tap do |identity|
      identity.oauth_token = auth['credentials']['token']
      identity.oauth_secret = auth['credentials']['secret']
      case auth['provider']
      when "twitter"
        identity.name = auth['info']['name']
        identity.nickname = auth['info']['nickname']
        identity.bio = auth['info']['description']
        identity.avatar_address = auth['info']['image']
      else
        raise "Provider #{provider} not handled"
      end
      identity.save
    end
  end

  def check_person
    if person_id.nil?
      p = create_person(nickname: nickname, name: name, remote_avatar_url: biggest_avatar)
      p.identities << self
    end
  end

  def biggest_avatar
    avatar_address.gsub('_bigger', '').gsub('_normal', '') if avatar_address
  end
end

class PersonMeta < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :landing_page, :mixpanel_id, :referrer_url, :person_id
  belongs_to :person

  def self.create_for_person(person, referrer, landing_page)
    PersonMeta.create!(referrer_url: referrer, landing_page: landing_page, person_id: person.id)
  end
end
```

So we have that, and we're not getting any errors in production.

Where do we start? Well, let's see if the point of failure is Identity.from_omniauth

This method searches for an existing identity (we've written extra code for more providers, but not implemented client-side yet). If no identity is found it will create one, and then create the associated Person model. If this was the point of failure we'd be able to see some suspiciously empty fields in the production console. But no - the Person & Identity models have all been created with all of the correct fields, and the relevant bits of the app have seen them (e.g. their 'user profile pages' have all been created).

I just added in the `if @person` to the #oauthorize - we had one 500 where `@identity.person` was `nil`, but haven't been able to replicate.

Anyway, the real-world users in question *do* have complete models with associations intact. Moving down the method we then create a `PersonMeta` record to record simple stuff like landing page. I'd have done this as an `after_create` on the `Person` but I figured it wasn't right to be passing session data to a model.

**This isn't being created for our problematic users**. At this point, I'm kind of stumped. I'm not sure how the create **!** (with bang) got in there, but shouldn't this be throwing an exception if somthing's broken? It isn't.

That is only called if it's a person's first visit anyway - subsequent logins should bypass it. One of the problematic users is a friend so I've been getting him to try out various other things, including signing in again, trying different browsers etc, and it **keeps happening**

## so anyway, after spending 45 minutes writing this post…

One of the users revoked access to the app via Twitter and reauthenticated. Everything works now.

What the hell?

His old identity *had* his OAuth tokens etc stored properly.

Luckily this is resolved for one user but it's obviously an ongoing problem.

What do we do?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the `identity.save` line in `Identity.from_omniauth` is failing silently? If so, your `after_create` hook won't run, `@identity.person` will be `nil`, and you'll just (silently) redirect.

Try `identity.save!` ?

Comment: I don't think so - as I say, for each of the users this has affected they've had valid & complete Identity & Person fields =/

Comment: Do you have any `PersonMeta`s with `nil` `person_id`s in the database?

Comment: Nope - they're either created properly or non-existent.